# An exercise in Mac Lane’s categories for working mathematician

Tags: category-theory

I try to solve problem 4 of section 1 in Chapter IV, but I can’t prove this statement:

Give functors $G:A\to X$ and $K:X\to A$ and natural transformations $\epsilon:KG\to Id_A$ and $\rho:Id_X\to GK$ such that $G\epsilon\cdot\rho G=1_G:G\to GKG\to G$. If $\epsilon K\cdot K\rho:K\to K=\alpha\cdot\beta$ and $\beta\cdot\alpha=1$, suppose $\beta:K\to F$ then $F$ is a left adjoint of $G$ with unit $G\beta\cdot\rho$  and counit $\epsilon\cdot \alpha G$.

I just define $\varphi(f)=Gf\circ G\beta_x\circ\rho_x$ for $f:Fx\to a$ and $\psi(g)=\epsilon_a\circ \alpha_{Ga}\circ Fg$ for $g:x\to Ga$ as usual and try to verify they are inverse function of each other. However it didn’t work and I found I can’t use the condition $\beta\cdot\alpha=1$ when I use this method to prove this statement. Can someone give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: You’ve been given the unit. It’s enough to verify it indeed is a unit, ie the initial object properties hold

Comment: I solved this problem, it's a bit complicated since it involves lots of natural transformations